# Programmatically Execute Workflow Action of an item from a URL

Tags: workflow, sitecore-api

I am trying to execute a Workflow Action "Approve" or "Reject" from a URL  to an ID, is my approach correct?

I need help finishing it, how do I run this code from a URL and how do run it on any ID, I want to try first on the specific Content Item that I already created in the Sitecore Content Tree.

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Workflows;
using Sitecore.Configuration;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;

namespace WorkflowStateChanger
{
  public class StateChanger
  {
  // Get Master Database
  private readonly Database _sourceDatabase = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
  // Item State Awaiting Approval
  Item AwaitingApproval = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{46DA5376-10DC-4B66-B464-AFDAA29DE84F}"));
  // get Approve Command by ID | ID specific
  Item Approve = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{F744CC9C-4BB1-4B38-8D5C-1E9CE7F45D2D}"));
  // get Reject Command by ID | ID specific
  Item Reject = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{E44F2D64-1EED-42FF-A7DA-C07B834096AC}"));
  public void Execute()
  {
  // Get item by ID (need to specify ID)
  // /sitecore/content/WorkflowTest | {D7D61874-0715-43E0-9093-E334A267B2A3}
  Item item = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID("{D7D61874-0715-43E0-9093-E334A267B2A3}"));
  }

  //set the item state and executes actions which are in this state:
  public void MoveToStateAndExecuteActions(Item item, ID workflowStateId)
  {
  IWorkflowProvider workflowProvider = Context.Database.WorkflowProvider;
  IWorkflow workflow = workflowProvider.GetWorkflow(item);

  // Begit Edit
  item.Editing.BeginEdit();
  try
  {
  item[FieldIDs.WorkflowState] = workflowStateId.ToString();
  item.Editing.EndEdit();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
  //Revert the Changes
  item.Editing.CancelEdit();
  }
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to show this right at the moment, but the work box has a RSS feed that exposes actual URL's for Workflow Actions.  You can decompile that logic and reuse those URL's elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to transition items through a workflow via web request.

Below are some options I can think of that require low effort.

#### Option 1 : Code Page

Save the code in a web page (.aspx) with query string parameters that are processed in the code you've provided. The query string could contain the GUIDs you have in the code sample.

#### Option 2 : SPE Web API

Convert the code into a PowerShell script and process using the [SPE Web API](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/web-api.html). There you can also supply query string parameters.

#### Final Thoughts

In either case, the method you choose needs to have security wrapped around it so unauthorized users are not hammering the Url or transitioning items through a workflow without proper privileges.

#### Resources

- [How to invoke Workflow on the particular item using Sitecore API?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8707/how-to-invoke-workflow-on-the-particular-item-using-sitecore-api)
- [Update workflow and state on content items.ps1](https://gist.github.com/marcduiker/950e0358bb4752ed5b047931a8c958c1)
- [Using the SPE Web API](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/web-api.html)

Comment: is my approach correct?

Comment: One of the links I referenced describes transitioning from one workflow state to another, which includes executing the associated actions. Whether or not the code sample you provided is the _best_ or _right_ way I cannot say. Perhaps you can clarify your question to include more details around why you want to accomplish through a url and any links to where you found the snippet.